# Network bandwidth measurement on Solaris

Tags: networking, software-installation, solaris, monitoring, bandwidth

I want to install `pathtest` or a program like it in a Sparc server running solaris 10. The purpose is to make a speedtest server to my remote sites.

It is mentioned in pathtest FAQ that it only installs in x86 Windows and Linux variants.

1. Is there a way to install it? or
2. Is there any equivalent function? (I've searched in sunfreeware but naught) or
3. Do I have to resort to install another OS on top of Solaris 10?

Comment: You should explain better what is pathtest and what of its functionalities you want. If it is closed source and provides only binaries for x86 Windows and Linux, there is no sensible way to run it on SPARC.

Answer (score 1):

I had to google for what pathtest is, and it seems to just be a iperf-like tool. If they only supply binaries, and do not provide binaries for Solaris sparc, then no, you cannot use it on that system.

If it truly is just a command line tool (I didn't download it, as while they claim it is free, you must fill out a form to request a copy), then there are a number of other apps you can use instead such as iperf or netperf.

Comment: yes tim, but definitely pathtest better than iperf since iperf floods TCP only while pathtest uses UDP, TCP & ICMP
iperf is also not accurate for GigE
http://www.appneta.com/2011/12/27/iperf-and-pathtest-an-engineers-experiment/
anyway, thanx for your effort @Timothy Butler. So now ill have to check for any 'pathtest' equivalent for Solaris 10...

Comment: The iperf docs say it does UDP, though note that there is a reimplementation of iperf labelled iperf3. Netperf also does UDP.